# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore generated api file isn't not satisfy the OAS 3 spec

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, nswag, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, nswagstudio

I use the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore @ v6.5.0 version to generate a OAS file.
while I find that the file generate is not satisfy the OAS spec.
Here is my c# code.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Inheritance and Polymorphism
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pet">pet</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost("Polymorphism", Name = "Polymorphism")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public void GetSample([FromBody] Pet pet)
        {
            return;
        }
```

```
    public class Dog : Pet
    {
        public bool Bark { get; set; }
    }
    public class Cat : Pet
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dog : Pet
    {
        public bool Bark { get; set; }
    }
```

While I got an api file like

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "NswagTest",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/TestControllerNameTags/Polymorphism": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "TestControllerNameTags"
        ],
        "summary": "Inheritance and Polymorphism",
        "operationId": "Polymorphism",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "pet",
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  },
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Cat"
                  },
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Dog"
                  }
                ],
                "description": "Pet"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Cat": {
        "type": "object",
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "Dog": {
        "type": "object",
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "bark": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "Pet": {
        "required": [
          "petType"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "petType": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": "Pet",
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "petType",
          "mapping": {
            "Cat": "#/components/schemas/Cat",
            "Dog": "#/components/schemas/Dog"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2 parts I think that not satisfy the OAS spec

The 1st is in the components->schemas->Cat, the type and properties should be an item of "allof"
The 2nd is the discriminator shoudl be the same level of "oneof" rather than in the base class definition.
like: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/

But a very strange issue that confuse me is the I can also use the Nswag to genereate a ts client correctly. So I don't know is there any misunderstanding for me about the OSA spec?

I searched in the github found that in some version of the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, the 1 and 2 are satified. but in the latest version(v6.5.0), both 1 and 2 are not satisfied.